# Get Data from POST request on client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-redux

I made a form post request from my react front end. In my express route I handle it, and I send the data to the browser, as such:

```
app.post("/api/fetchuser", async (req, res) => {
  // Doing some stuff here

  res.send(req.body.user);
});
```

**My question is:** How can I get the data from this POST request route back to my client side? Previously, I did `axios.get(...)` to retrieve data on a `app.get(...)` route in a similar fashion, however, this is a POST route. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you tried axios.post?

Comment: I read up on it, but Im not posting more data to backend. I want to retrieve data from post route. Can i do that? If so can you post an answer :)

Comment: If you are not posting data then you must create a get route on backend?

Comment: Or else you send the body as empty and then post it.

Comment: What about writing your query and then having the sql string end with something like 'SELECT * ... RETURNING ID;' ???

Comment: Posted an answer that post an empty object to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `axios.post` request. See **Performing a POST request** section of [axios documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

Edit: Yes you can also retrieve data by `POST` request. You don't have to post any data to the server while performing the request.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of that. Also, does that mean I have to do a manual post request instead of using the <form method="post">. If so how would I implement that over the form method?

Comment: Well you don't have to - You can. Both methods are valid. The difference is that in a first scenario you just POST your data using good old HTML form and synchronous request (page will reload). If you would like to use Axios to POST your form data to the server you can connect it to your form and make asynchronous request (page won't reload, think of Ajax).

Comment: There are many ways how to do this. Basically you need to do 3 main steps in your javascript: 1. Prevent form from submitting, 2. on form submit, instead of making the request collect all the data from the form and 3. using something like Axios make the request.

Answer (score 0):

axios.post('/api/fetchuser/',{})
          .then(res => console.log(res.data));

Comment: I can see an issue with this however. Since im posting data via my form method. That same route data won't be accessible when I perform another post request via axios. I'm just posting an empty object to the route. It's not a .get route where the data will persist on the page regardless if the page is reloaded. That's not the case with a post route, Once you refresh the page the data will vanish